# Will I lose my student Aufenthaltstitel if I take an academic leave for pregnancy?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, student-visa

I am a Ukrainian citizen currently studying in Germany and I have my Aufenthaltstitel valid till October 2017. 
I am taking academic leave for pregnancy for couple of years starting from the next semester in April.
However, I have an important journey planned in April to Spain, Germany and Netherlands and I need to use my Aufenthaltstitel for this journey, as the procedure of getting tourist visa in Ukraine is rather unreliable.

The question is: if I take my academic leave from the university, but I don't de-register from my German address and I continue to pay my student medical insurance, will I be able to travel in April with my aufenthaltstitel?

p.s. and will my Aufenthaltstitel will be valid till October if I de-register from the address?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Will you be physically staying in Germany or in Ukraine during your pregnancy leave and maternity leave?

Comment: I guess the more sure-fire way is certainly to go to your local Bürgeramt and ask them for clarification?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.